# Python Using Adblock with Selenium and Firefox Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox-addon, adblock

My goal is to use Adblock Plus with Selenium via Python. I have been able to get it to the point where it will load the extension, but by default it does not include the default filter "EasyList." Here is what I have so far:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from time import sleep
 ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
 adblockfile = '/Users/username/Downloads/adblock_plus-2.4-tb+fx+an+sm.xpi'
 ffprofile.add_extension(adblockfile)
 ffprofile.set_preference("extensions.adblockplus.currentVersion", "2.4")
 browser = webdriver.Firefox(ffprofile)
 while(True):
    browser.get("www.cnn.com")
    sleep(5)
```

Most of this code was ripped off of http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html

Comment: Sounds like out of the scope of Selenium, basically you want to change the settings of an extension. I doubt if this is achievable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, Adblock Plus will add EasyList by default - but not if you set `extensions.adblockplus.currentVersion` preference to disable update/first-run actions. I guess that your goal was preventing the first-run page from showing up but it also prevented data storage initialization. Note that you have more issues here: even if Adblock Plus adds EasyList, it will still take an unknown time to download.

The better course of action should be initializing your profile with an existing `adblockplus/patterns.ini` file. You can get this file from your regular Firefox profile, with EasyList and other filter settings, and copy it to `/Users/username/Downloads/profilemodel/adblockplus/patterns.ini`. Then the following should work:

```
ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("/Users/username/Downloads/profilemodel");
```

Comment: To find the path of your profile open the `about:support` page in Firefox.

Comment: @koksderdrache: There is little point improving this answer, it is massively outdated. The entire Firefox extension ecosystem is completely different from what it was back in 2013.

Comment: you're probably right. In the end I switched to a ChromeDriver and used chromes extension.

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way to do this:

1) extract adblock.xpi with 7-zip or equivalent

2) open /modules/AppIntegration.jsm with a regular text editor

3) find the function declaration for "notifyUser()", and replace this with a simple return. for example:

```
/**
* function notifyUser()
* {
*   let wrapper = (wrappers.length ? wrappers[0] : null);
*   if (wrapper && wrapper.addTab)
*   {
*       wrapper.addTab("chrome://adblockplus/content/ui/firstRun.xul");
*   }
*   else
*   {
*       Utils.windowWatcher.openWindow(wrapper ? wrapper.window : null,
*                                                                    "chrome://adblockplus/content/ui/firstRun.xul",
*                                                                    "_blank", "chrome,centerscreen,resizable,dialog=no", null);
*   }
* }
*/

function notifyUser()
{
    return;
}
```

Now you just need to package the files back into a zip, and change the extension from .zip to .xpi -- Voila!

This will stop adblock from loading the welcome page, but it will still configure the necessary subscription settings.  Make sure **NOT** to call

```
ffprofile.set_preference("extensions.adblockplus.currentVersion", "x.x.x")
```

Otherwise, it will not know to "boot itself"

Please note that this is for adblock_plus-2.0.3 since I'm using firefox-17. The code may be slightly different, and in a different location for newer versions. See: https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/206#comment:5

Answer (score 0):

I just recently found out how to block the first-run page without any issues by trial and error:

1. Go to the folder where your extension is located
2. In `lib/adblockplus.js`, set `defaults.suppress_first_run_page` to `true` instead of `false`.