# Python selenium firefox adblock

Tags: python

I am trying to load a version of firefox with adblock but i am getting an error.

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
adblockfile = '\Users\username\Downloads\adblock_plus-2.6.3-fx+an+sm+tb.xpi'
profile.add_extension (adblockfile)
profile.set_preference("extensions.adblockplus.currentVersion", "2.4")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

error reads

```
the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: ' c:\\users\\username\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmplt8yt3.download\x07dblock_plus-2.6.3-fx+an+sm+tb.xpi'
```

Not to sure what is going on and why the directory is messing up.

Comment: windows, im not too sure what you mean, sorry im really new still learning.

Answer (score 0):

```
adblockfile = '\Users\username\Downloads\adblock_plus-2.6.3-fx+an+sm+tb.xpi'
```

should be

```
adblockfile = r'\Users\username\Downloads\adblock_plus-2.6.3-fx+an+sm+tb.xpi'
```

otherwise, some backslashed characters (in this case, the `'\a'`) get interpreted as escape sequences.

[The `r` prefix before the quotation mark](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) makes the string a raw string and tells Python to interpret the backslash as a literal backslash.

---

`'\a'` is the   ASCII Bell (BEL) character, whereas `r'\a'` is a literal backslash followed by an `a`:

```
In [179]: '\adblock'
Out[179]: '\x07dblock'

In [180]: r'\adblock'
Out[180]: '\\adblock'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have further issues with loading the xpi since adblock will need to get its subscription list.  Please see

[Python Using Adblock with Selenium and Firefox Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832159/python-using-adblock-with-selenium-and-firefox-webdriver/26635985#26635985)

Or you can save a profile that already has the subscription list downloaded