# Python Selenium add_extensions close install splash screen

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am loading Firefox with an extension list so...

```
 ffprofile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
 ffprofile.add_extension(extension="ff_extensions/myextension.xpi")
 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=ffprofile)
 return driver
```

This works but the extension opens up it's install complete splash screen.  Is there a way to disable these from showing or a way to close all tabs on launch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to issue `driver.quit()` which in case of Firefox should close the tab.

Or, call `CTRL/COMMAND + W` shortcut to close the current tab:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, "p").perform()  # or Keys.COMMAND on Mac
```

Also, *depending on the extension*, this kind of welcome/first-run behavior could be controlled through the *firefox preferences*. For example, here is how to disable it in case of AdBlock: [Python Using Adblock with Selenium and Firefox Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832159/python-using-adblock-with-selenium-and-firefox-webdriver).

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the link.  Working on it now but looks like exactly what I need

Comment: Just for anyone looking here in the future, the problem detailed in the link has now been resolved which makes things even easier